# bootstrap layout - stick footer and content row to the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing this site: http://ecostructionny.com. I'm just at the point where I'm laying out the home page and I'm a bit stuck. I want a footer row at the bottom that lists contact info, and then directly above it is a row of 3 blurbs of information. The background images are the main visual feature of the page, so I'm trying to leave space for them to show through.

Can anyone help with some suggestions? If there's a better way to lay it out, I'd love some other advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good footer tutorial at

http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/

The demo page is here:

http://www.lwis.net/profile/CSS/sticky-footer.html

The basic premise is that the main body page is stretched to a 100% of the page. With a min-height of 100% too.

The footer is then given the following rules:

```
   #footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you know you will get as many ideas as people that respond. Everyone's opinion is different when it comes to design. Based on your statement above I would direct you to the bootstrap sticky-footer example that comes with the download of bootstrap. In addition, in my experience, it works better if you do some work and resize the photos so they appear natural in the carousel. When images are stretched to fit it distorts things a bit. Take some time and experiment. Also, I have found that using the hero template page with bootstrap works really well for the thing you are trying to do. Experiment around.!!

Tony Tambe: bootstrap has all the responsive code yes, but you will have to add some @media queries to your styling to make the header resize and the underline under the title move down etc. You can add @media query in the html page using a style element (In the head section). Keep experimenting, is looking good.

Comment: Thanks vbmike. I've been experimenting for weeks to see what the best way to use the carousel would be. I want the "blubs" to lay over the carousel, but the footer to stick to the bottom. I saw the sticky footer elsewhere, so I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The one example I have incorporated in my start-templates is at this site: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Thanks again vbmike. I've adjusted it pretty good now, but I have a follow up question if you don't mind. IF you check it out now, you'll see that resizing the browser window eventually shows the grey background, and the navbar continues. Any styling tips for that? I could adjust a regular navbar, but bootstrap has all of the responsive code, so I don't want to start messing with it too much.